# dpkg -S <filename> yields "dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern"

Tags: linux, linux-mint, dpkg

Why does `dpkg -S` yields the title error on some commands?

For example:

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/firefox
   firefox: /usr/bin/firefox
```

But then this:

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/ls
   dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/ls
```

Answer (score 10):

The [`/usr` merge](https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge) takes years to be achieved and is still ongoing. In particular, today:

> - `bash`, `base-files`, `coreutils`, `dash`, `glibc`, `util-linux` **should not move files from `/` to `/usr`**:
>
>   - The upload of these packages needs to be synced.

`ls` used to be part of the "important" commands in `/bin` rather than `/usr/bin`. Now `/bin` is simply a symbolic link to `/usr/bin`:

```shell
$ ls -ld /bin /sbin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Nov 17  2020 /bin -> usr/bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Nov 17  2020 /sbin -> usr/sbin
```

The difference is not very visible. The usual `PATH` environment variable being (I pruned it a bit):

```shell
$ printenv PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

`/usr/bin/ls` is found before `/bin/ls` even if both paths provide the command.

Yet, the package providing the `ls` command still installs it in `/bin/ls` in Debian, Ubuntu and Linux Mint (the two latter being a derivative of the former). In the end, because of the symbolic link, it becomes `/usr/bin/ls`. Because of this:

```shell
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/ls
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/ls
$ dpkg -S /bin/ls
coreutils: /bin/ls
```

So you have to search for both paths for any command in `/usr/bin`. Likewise for `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin`. The "basic" commands which were historically deemed enough to boot the system to a state where `/usr` could be mounted if needed will end up found in `/bin` and `/sbin`, others in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin`.

One can imagine that in a future (and yet unknown) release of Debian, Ubuntu and Linux Mint, the synced move of various packages installing from `/` to `/usr` will be done and that `dpkg -S /usr/bin/ls` would then give a result instead of `dpkg -S /bin/ls`.

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg -S /usr/bin/ls` won't work as `ls` command is an alias command. To check that, you can use this command :

```
$ type -t ls
alias

$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /usr/bin/ls
ls is /bin/ls
```

`ls` command belongs to `coreutils` package that contains a lot of basic commands :

> arch base64 basename cat chcon chgrp chmod chown chroot cksum comm cp
> csplit cut date dd df dir dircolors dirname du echo env expand expr
> factor false flock fmt fold groups head hostid id install join link ln
> logname ls md5sum mkdir mkfifo mknod mktemp mv nice nl nohup nproc numfmt
> od paste pathchk pinky pr printenv printf ptx pwd readlink realpath rm
> rmdir runcon sha*sum seq shred sleep sort split stat stty sum sync tac
> tail tee test timeout touch tr true truncate tsort tty uname unexpand
> uniq unlink users vdir wc who whoami yes

`dpkg -S` will work with :

```
$ dpkg -S /bin/ls
coreutils: /bin/ls
```

It is the same behavior with all basic Linux commands (`touch`, `mv`, `cp`, `mkdir`, `dd` etc…).

Comment: I agree with the final command, but not at all with the alias explanation.

Comment: The `-a` option to `type` is the most important takeaway here. Without it I only see the (superficial color) alias. Even `which ls` reports /usr/bin/ls. I'm sure there's at least one other command to find programs, but can't remember it now (it's not where, locate or find might technically work but it's not those...)